# TypeScript Compiler: How to avoid compiler error when using Generics

Tags: angular, typescript

The following interface is used to define a JSON API response.
The status field tells whether the request was successful or not.
The data filed is used to set data(only if available) returned by the server upon successful requests.
Similarly the message field is used to set error messages upon failed requests.

```
export interface IResponse<T> {
    status: 'success' | 'fail';
    data?: T;
    message?: string;
}
```

Suppose I have the following function that fetches some company data from the server.
The response contains either data or string.

```
search(keyword: string): Observable<IResponse<ICompany[]|string>> {
   return this.searchCompany(keyword);
}
```

When I try to call this function as follows, I get a compile error as **data** could either be *ICompany[]* or *string*.

```
this.dataImportService.search('')
      .subscribe(
        data => {
         data.data[0].company_name // compile error 
      }, err => {
      });
```

What should I do to get rid of this compile error?

Comment: Can you try `data.data[0].company_name`?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner sorry, missed that ".data" part. I am getting the compiler error with data.data[0].xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript compiler has some trouble working with nested property like `data.data`. The trick is to use a temporary variable `const data = data.data`. Then the TypeScript compiler behaves as expected: the `typeof data === ...` [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) is working i.e. the union type `ICompany[] | string` can be narrowed to `ICompany[]` or `string` inside the `if (typeof data === ...)` block.

Renaming `data` to `response` (to be less confusing), we have:

```js
this.dataImportService.search('').subscribe(response => {
    const data = response.data; // inferred type: ICompany[]|string
    if (typeof data !== 'string' && data.length) {
        const firstCompany = data[0]; // inferred type: ICompany
        firstCompany.company_name; // OK
    }
});
```

[Live in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IResponse%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20status%3A%20%27success%27%20%7C%20%27fail%27%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3F%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20message%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ICompany%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20company_name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Observable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subscribe(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20observerOrNext%3F%3A%20(value%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20complete%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20search(keyword%3A%20string)%3A%20Observable%3CIResponse%3CICompany%5B%5D%7Cstring%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20return%20this.searchCompany(keyword)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20---%0D%0A%0D%0Asearch(%27%27).subscribe(response%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20data%20%3D%20response.data%3B%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%3A%20ICompany%5B%5D%7Cstring%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20data%20!%3D%3D%20%27string%27%20%26%26%20data.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20firstCompany%20%3D%20data%5B0%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%3A%20ICompany%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20firstCompany.company_name%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the compile error you could use <any> to avoid type checking.

```
this.dataImportService.search('')
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => { // <- here
         data.data[0].company_name // compile error 
      }, err => {
});
```

But really you should not do that. Typescript is just warning you that if your search method returns a string you will have an error or at least unexpected behavior.

Say search return 'hoho or whatever', data.data will be 'hoho or whatever' data.data[0] = 'h'; data.data[0].company_name will be undefined.